# Case insensitive RegEx pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want to search for strings that have: `Code[spaces]VARCHAR`

Currently I'm using: `\bCode\s+VARCHAR\b`

How would I make this case insensitive?

Comment: We need to know the regex engine you're using to give you the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

Try this

```
/\bCode\s+VARCHAR\b/i
```

**Or**

```
(?i)\bCode\s+VARCHAR\b
```

[Explained here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28?i%29%5CbCode%5Cs%2bVARCHAR%5Cb)

Comment: It's `(?i)` and not `?i`. Also it doesn't make sense to set it several times in a pattern.

Comment: That was a quick response. That explained link is great! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Which Regex engine do you use ? 
For most of them you can give a 'i' flag (insensitive) at the end of your regex

Like that :

```
/\bCode\s+VARCHAR\b/i
```

or sometimes as a function parameter :

```
string.match("\bCode\s+VARCHAR\b", "i")
```

Answer (score 1):

In java (and other languages too) you can add the case insensitive flag `(?i)` right in the regex:

```
(?i)\bCode\s+VARCHAR\b
```